# Proof of Asymptotic Relations

Tags: algorithms, logarithms, asymptotics

I am new to the study of algorithms in computer science and I encountered a very unusual problem.

```
Let f; g : N -> R be two real-valued functions greater than 1. Consider the following
two statements:
(A) f(n) = Theta(g(n))
(B) log f(n) ~ log g(n)
```

Here I have to prove that B does follow from A when we assume that f(n) -> Infinity.

Till now, I have worked up with the definitions of asymptotic similarities and tried to compare with the definition of theta, but unsuccessful as I am not able to get satisfactory proof.
Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Show that (A) is equivalent to $\log{f(n)}=\log{g(n)}+O(1)$.

Comment: Does $\sim$ mean that $\lim|\frac{f}{g}|=1$?

Comment: @Alex yes it means the same.

Comment: @Mindlack can you further explain how can I derive that relation?

Comment: Just write $f=hg$ for some function $h$ and write explicitly what $f=\Theta(g)$ means for $h$.

Answer (score 0):

I think $\sim$ means the limit is $1$, and I don't think that's the case. You have:
$$
f(n) \geq c_1 g(n) \ \forall \ n>n_0\\
\lim_n|\frac{f}{g}| \geq c_1
$$
Assuming both $f$ and $g>0$ for all $n>n_1$, you can take the logs:
$$
L^{f}_{n} = \log f(n)\\
L^{g}_{n} = \log g(n)
$$
Therefore, you can take the limit:
$$
\lim_n (L^{f}_{n} - L^{g}_{n})=\lim_n \log \frac{f}{g}=\log \lim\frac{f}{g} \geq \log c_1 = c_2
$$
The limit and logarithm can be interchanged because logarithm is a continuous function. Here $c_2$ can be negative. Take for example $f_n = 5e^n$ and $g_n=4e^n$, $\log\frac{5}{4}<0$

Comment: Yes, but the ratio of $\log{f}$ and $\log{g}$ still goes to one, which is what is asked.

Comment: @Alex your explaination is awesome. Have you considered the fact that what if f(n) -> Infinity? If we substitute f(n) as infinite in your equation, the answer will be infinite.