# What does $f(n)$ $\rightarrow \infty $ imply?

Tags: limits, algorithms, asymptotics, recurrence-relations

Let $f, g :$ $ \mathbb{N}  \rightarrow   \mathbb{R} $ be two real-valued functions greater than $1$. Consider the following two statements:

(A)$ f(n) =$ $ \Theta (g(n))$

(B) $\log f(n) \sim \log g(n)$

(a) Prove: (B) does not follow from (A). (Give a counterexample.)

(b) Prove: (B) does follow from (A) if we make a stronger assumption that $f(n)$ $\rightarrow \infty $

I am very confused about part $b$. Does  $f(n)$ $\rightarrow \infty $ mean that the function is approaching infinity, that is, it is an increasing function, but then how would it help in solving it?

Comment: Have you already done (a)? Finding a counterexample should help you to see why the added assumption makes a difference. $f(n)\to\infty$ means that $\lim_{n\to\infty}f(n)=\infty$. This does not imply that the function is increasing everywhere: you could have $f(n)=n+(-1)^n$, for instance.

Comment: See [Proof of Asymptotic Relations](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3829045/proof-of-asymptotic-relations).

Comment: For part a, I used f(n) = 2n^2 and g(n) = n^2. I proved it using c1 = 1 and c2 = 3, hence proving that 0 <= c1g(n) <= f (n) <= c2g(n) for all n >= n0. @BrianM.Scott

Comment: @Icarus: Since $2n^2\to\infty$, that cannot possibly be a counterexample if (b) is actually true. And in fact $\frac{\log 2n^2}{\log n^2}=\frac{\log 2+\log n^2}{\log n^2}\to 1$ as $n\to\infty$, so it’s not a counterexample.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since (b) is true, there cannot be a counterexample in (a) for which $\lim_\limits{n\to\infty}f(n)=\infty$. HINT: There are counterexamples in which $f$ and $g$ are both constant functions.

Here’s a sketch to get you started on (b).

Suppose that $c_1g(n)\le f(n)\le c_2g(n)$ for all $n\ge n_0$, and that $\lim_\limits{n\to\infty}f(n)=\infty$. Then $\log c_1+\log g(n)\le\log f(n)\le\log c_2+\log g(n)$ for all $n\ge n_0$, so

$$\frac{\log c_1+\log g(n)}{\log g(n)}\le\frac{\log f(n)}{\log g(n)}\le\frac{\log c_2+\log g(n)}{\log g(n)}$$

for all $n\ge n_0$.

Now use the fact that $f(n)=\Theta\big(g(n)\big)$ to show that $\lim_\limits{n\to\infty}g(n)=\infty$, and conclude that

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\log c_1+\log g(n)}{\log g(n)}=1=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\log c_2+\log g(n)}{\log g(n)}\,.$$

Comment: Hi professor Scott, could I ask your assistance [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3830253/a-a-totally-ordered-set-without-maximum-and-minimum-such-that-any-bounded-subset), please?